# Jetpack compose how to skip one item in a LazyVerticalGrid / java.lang.IllegalStateException: Check failed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazyvgrid, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

i'am starting to work with jetpack compose. i'am creating a grid to display some Box with some text. the problem is that i get my data from my api and some might be null. So i would like to skip this item in my grid but it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
val spanCount = 2
LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(spanCount),
    state = rememberLazyListState(),
) {
            items(datafromapi) { result ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                                    .clickable {
                                       //todo
                                    }
                                    .padding(8.dp)) {
                                    Text(result.title)
                                }
        }
```

The Result that i get from the api, is an object with multiples string, and title is one of them than i need to use here. The problem is that sometime title is null then when it's happening i get this error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2987)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:433)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:269)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.access$subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:154)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:244)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:241)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.withNoObservations(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:142)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:55)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.withNoSnapshotReadObservation$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1175)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:241)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:235)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcompose$ui_release(SubcomposeLayout.kt:224)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:490)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutPlaceablesProvider.getAndMeasure-0kLqBqw(LazyMeasurePolicy.kt:58)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyMeasuredItemProvider.getAndMeasure-oA9-DU0(LazyMeasuredItemProvider.kt:45)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyListMeasureKt.measureLazyList-wroFCeY(LazyListMeasure.kt:145)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyListKt$rememberLazyListMeasurePolicy$1$1.measure-3p2s80s(LazyList.kt:259)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$2.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:55)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$2.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:44)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:355)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:55)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:306)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:75)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1308)
```

So i thought it's because my title is null and i wanted to add a check on this but it doesn't seems to work i tried to add a check before is box initiation :

```
val spanCount = 2
LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(spanCount),
    state = rememberLazyListState(),
) {
            items(datafromapi) { result ->
            if (!result.tile.isNullOrEmpty){
               Box(modifier = Modifier
                                    .clickable {
                                       //todo
                                    }
                                    .padding(8.dp)) {
                                    Text(result.title)
                                }
                    }
        }
```

But it didn't solve my problem and i got an other error :

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Check failed.
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyGridKt$ItemRow$2.measure-3p2s80s(LazyGrid.kt:451)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:55)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:75)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1308)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutPlaceablesProvider.getAndMeasure-0kLqBqw(LazyMeasurePolicy.kt:61)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyMeasuredItemProvider.getAndMeasure-oA9-DU0(LazyMeasuredItemProvider.kt:45)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyListMeasureKt.measureLazyList-wroFCeY(LazyListMeasure.kt:145)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyListKt$rememberLazyListMeasurePolicy$1$1.measure-3p2s80s(LazyList.kt:259)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$2.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:55)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$2.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:44)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:355)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:55)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:306)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:88)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:76)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:98)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:75)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1308)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt$rowColumnMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(RowColumnImpl.kt:89)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:55)
```

So i tried to put the condition inside the box before the text like this :

```
if (!issue.title.isNullOrEmpty()){
    Text(issue.title)}
```

This is working with no crash the problem is that i have an empty blank box in my grid that i would like to get rid of.

So i the end i just want to add a check on the items of my grid and in a certain condition to not display the item. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest some approaches:

1. If you have a State Holder (ViewModel or a plain class) that holds the state for your Composables, make the validations there and filter the null values before getting to the view.
2. You could use the remember and then use that in your list:

```
    val dataFiltered = remember { mutableStateListOf(datafromapi.filter { it.title.isNullOrBlank().not() }) }
```

3. Filter the data from your API so any client will get the right values instead of nulls.

I don't really like the second option, but that could be one.

What is happening with your validation is considered a Side Effect, because is an external behavior affecting your Composables, so the best approach would be to handle this externally before the data reaches your UI.

Comment: This should be the correct approach. Wherever you are fetching your data (being a data layer or a state holder), you should filter out the ones with a null title. This way, the view (LazyVerticalGrid) doesn't have to worry about manipulating the data and can focus on rendering it.